# Como passar o valor de uma variável php em um link javascript dentro de um script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Tenho um script com um link e uma variável, como passar o valor desta variável dentro do link no script?

```
if($mensagem_post == "1"){
    echo'<script> swal({
    title: "Você tem certeza?",
    text: "Este arquivo não poderá ser visualizado mais!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#000",
    confirmButtonText: "Sim, deletar!",
    cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",

    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
  },
  function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
      swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo foi excluido", "success");
      setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.dpauladesigner.com.br?id_teste=.<?php $id_teste. ?>";
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo está salvo", "error");
    }
  }); </script>';
```

O resultado do link sai este:
http://www.dpauladesigner.com.br/?id_teste=.%3C?php%20$id_teste.%20?%3E
e não sai o valor da minha variável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No código postado detectei os seguintes erros:**

1. Falta da chave `}` de fechamento relativa a  `if($mensagem_post`......
2. A linha abaixo

`window.location.href = "http://www.dpauladesigner.com.br?id_teste=.<?php $id_teste. ?>";`

contem uma tag PHP  `<?php $id_teste. ?>` dentro de um echo que ainda é PHP

o correto é

`window.location.href = "http://www.dpauladesigner.com.br?id_teste='.$id_teste.'";`

Não obstante, o código correto é:  [**Exemplo - Ideone**](https://ideone.com/WIoaqn)

```
 if($mensagem_post == "1"){
      echo'<script> swal({
      title: "Você tem certeza?",
      text: "Este arquivo não poderá ser visualizado mais!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#000",
      confirmButtonText: "Sim, deletar!",
      cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",

      closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
     },
     function(isConfirm){
       if (isConfirm) {
         swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo foi excluido", "success");
         setTimeout(function(){
         window.location.href = "http://www.dpauladesigner.com.br?id_teste='.$id_teste.'";
       }, 2000);
       } else {
        swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo está salvo", "error");
       }
    }); </script>';

 }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo você fazer de uma outra forma. Caso você esteja chamando o `sweet alert` na mesma página aonde você define a variável PHP, então pode-se fazer assim:

```
<?php
$id_teste = 10;
?>
<script> 
swal({
    title: "Você tem certeza?",
    text: "Este arquivo não poderá ser visualizado mais!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#000",
    confirmButtonText: "Sim, deletar!",
    cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",

    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
  },
  function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
      swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo foi excluido", "success");
      setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.dpauladesigner.com.br?id_teste=<?php $id_teste;?>";
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo está salvo", "error");
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

Mas lembre-se é só no caso de você estiver colocando o javascript junto ao arquivo .php que gera a variável `$id_teste` ...

Caso você tenha uma página .php e nele você só chama um arquivo .js você pode fazer assim:

**alert.js**

```
swal({
    title: "Você tem certeza?",
    text: "Este arquivo não poderá ser visualizado mais!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#000",
    confirmButtonText: "Sim, deletar!",
    cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",

    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
  },
  function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
      swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo foi excluido", "success");
      setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.dpauladesigner.com.br?id_teste="+ID_TESTE;
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      swal("Cancelado", "Seu arquivo está salvo", "error");
    }
  });
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$id_teste = 10;
?>

<script>
var ID_TESTE = '<?php echo $id_teste;?>';
</script>
<script src="alert.js"></script>
```

Resumindo o exemplo anterior, na página PHP você cria uma tag `<script>` e dentro dela você cria variaveis javascript com o conteúdo do PHP. Assim, quando carregar o arquivo .JS ele vai puxar a variável que está dentro da tag `<script>`